# AWS - VPC Limits - Efficient Infrastructure

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

For my fairly modest web application, I seem to be hitting some of the AWS VPC limits, which made wonder if I'm maybe structuring things incorrectly:

- I have an application for which we have three environments: `Staging`, `QA`, `Production`.  So I have a VPC for each.
- These three VPCs exist in the US-East-1 Region
- Each Application is available in two availability zones (`us-east-1b` & `us-east-1c`)

An example of a limit I'm hitting is for the following circumstance:

- I have Public and Private facing subnets.  And because I'm using two Availability Zones, I have Public and Private Subnets for each (4 subnets in total, per VPC)
- The Private Subnets need internet access, so their respective Route Tables have entries for NAT Gateways.

So in the end, this means each Private Subnet has a NAT Gateway, and therefore each NAT Gateway has an Elastic IP.  And because I have three environments, and two Availability Zones for each, that's already 6 Elastic IP addresses, and the Elastic IP limit per Region is 5.

So obviously, I can request an increase, but it made me wonder if I'm doing something wrong.  Could some of these resources in fact share NAT Gateways, or Elastic IPs, or something to that effect?

Comment: Perhaps a silly question but why not have all three applications in the same VPC?

Comment: @Anand I suppose that's possible, however they share zero resources so it seemed more logical to have them in separate VPCs. Also keep in mind, the limit i'm experiencing is per Region, not per VPC.  So even if they were all in the same VPC, I'd still have the same problem.  Unless you're suggesting they use the same NAT Gateway when in the same VPC?

Comment: yes I see VPC as my own cloud so I'm not sure I would need more than one. And yes, share the NAT Gateway plus whether they share the same resources or not, I see no reason not to coexist in a VPC. I'm new to this so please don't take my opinion as authoritative, it's more like I'm learning with you :)

Comment: @Anand I see your point.  From the research I've done, I believe that's an option.  I think having separate VPCs is also quite common -- ie. so there's no chance of Staging / Dev work accidentally accessing your Production components or vice-versa.  I believe some companies even do separate consolidated billing accounts for each Environment (which is overkill for my situation).  See https://charity.wtf/2016/03/23/aws-networking-environments-and-you/

Comment: You're doing it exactly like you're supposed to. Another common approach is to use different accounts for Dev-Stage-Production. Then use cross-account roles and consolidated billing on top of those accounts. Since limits are per account, you will not hit them anytime soon.

Comment: Why do you need an Elastic IP for NAT instance?

Comment: @DusanBajic It's not a NAT instance, it's a managed AWS NAT Gateway and that requires an EIP.

Comment: @DusanBajic The NATs are associated with Private Subnets so that instances within those subnets can access the internet, but not vice versa.  The NATs need to be associated with an Elastic IP to facilitate this

Comment: @SergeyKovalev Thanks for the info Sergey.  I'll request an increase on Elastic IPs in that case

Comment: You say that your webapp is modest, but I would disagree. You have 3 environments, each has multiple tiers, and each is multi-AZ, with NAT redundancy within a zone and across zones. Go ahead and request an EIP quota increase.

Comment: Indeed, I was not aware that Elastic IP is not optional for NAT gateway. Still, (I hope) one NAT gateway can be used for both private subnets in one VPC.

Comment: @DusanBajic a NAT Gateway can serve as many subnets within a VPC as you like, but you'll pay cross-A/Z transport for the data if the subnet is in a different region from the gateway, and you have that theoretical risk of loss of one availability zone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not doing anything wrong, but you could be doing some things better.

Since you have 3 separated environments, you could separate the environments into separated AWS accounts.

For example, it's not uncommon to have Development in one AWS account, and Staging + Production in another AWS account. This has the added benefit of separating resources, identities, etc. for security purposes and avoids "oh $@&!, I just deleted the production stack by mistake".